# How do I test a trigger with an approval process?

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I have a trigger which initiates an approval process when certain criteria are met:

```
trigger AddendumAfterIHMS on Addendum__c (after update) {

  for (integer i = 0; i<Trigger.new.size(); i++){

    if(Trigger.new[i].RecordTypeId != '012V0000000CkQA'){

        if(Trigger.new[i].From_IHMS__c != null && Trigger.old[i].From_IHMS__c == null){

            ID addendumId = Trigger.new[i].Id;

            // Start next approval process
            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest request = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            request.setObjectId(addendumId);
            Approval.ProcessResult requestResult = Approval.process(request);

        }
    }
  }
}
```

It works perfectly, but now i need to create a test class for it.  I have created a class which brings the code up to 75% coverage, which is the minimum, but I'm picky and like to have 100% coverage on my code.  The test class I have now gets stuck on the line `request.setObjectId(addendumId);` and doesn't move past it.  The error I receive is:

```
System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0CV0000000B8cgMAC; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, AddendumAfterIHMS: execution of AfterUpdate
```

Here is the test class that I have written so far, most of the class actually tests some other triggers, but the important line which is throwing the error is the very last line `update addendumTierFeature;`

```
@isTest
private class AddendumTest {

static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

    // Query Testing Account, will need ID changed before testing to place into production
    Account existingAccount = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];
    Model__c existingModel = [SELECT Id FROM Model__c WHERE Active__c = TRUE LIMIT 1];
    Pricebook2 existingPricebook = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Pricebook2 WHERE IsActive = TRUE LIMIT 1];
    List<Contact> existingContacts = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Contact LIMIT 2];

    Contact existingContactPrimary = existingContacts[0];
    Contact existingContactSecondary = existingContacts[1];

    Opportunity newOpportunity = new Opportunity(

        Name = 'New Opportunity',
        Account = existingAccount,
        CloseDate = Date.today(),
        Order_Proposed__c = Date.today(),
        StageName = 'Branch Visit - Not Responding',
        Opportunity_Follow_Up__c = 'Every 120 Days',
        LeadSource = 'Farm Lists',
        Source_Detail__c = 'FSBO',
        Model_Name__c = existingModel.Id,
        Processing_Fee__c = 100.50,
        Site_State__c = 'OR',
        base_Build_Zone__c = 'OR',
        Pricebook_from_Lead__c = existingPricebook.Name

    );

    insert newOpportunity;
    //system.assert(newOpportunity.Id != null);

    ID newOppId = newOpportunity.Id;

    OpportunityContactRole contactPrimary = new OpportunityContactRole(
        Role = 'Primary',
        IsPrimary = true,
        OpportunityId = newOppId,
        ContactId = existingContactPrimary.Id
    );

    OpportunityContactRole contactSecondary = new OpportunityContactRole(
        Role = 'Primary',
        IsPrimary = false,
        OpportunityId = newOppId,
        ContactId = existingContactPrimary.Id
    );

    insert contactPrimary;
    insert contactSecondary;

    newOpportunity.Name = 'Different - Updating';
    newOpportunity.Order_Accepted__c = Datetime.now();

    update newOpportunity;

    Addendum__c addendumCustomOption = new Addendum__c(
        RecordTypeId = '012V0000000CkQA', //Pre Priced Custom Option
        Opportunity__c = newOppId,
        Item_Pre_Priced_Description__c = 'a1eV00000004DNu',
        Reason__c = 'This is a reason',
        Item__c = 'This is an Item',
        Quantity__c = 1
    );

    Addendum__c addendumTierFeature = new Addendum__c(
        RecordTypeId = '012V0000000Cjks', //Tier Feature
        Opportunity__c = newOppId,
        Category__c = 'Countertops',
        Reason__c = 'This is a reason',
        Item__c = 'This is an Item',
        Quantity__c = 1
    );

    insert addendumCustomOption;
    insert addendumTierFeature;

    addendumCustomOption.Quantity__c = 2;
    addendumTierFeature.Quantity__c = 2;

    update addendumCustomOption;
    update addendumTierFeature;
    update newOpportunity;

    addendumTierFeature.To_IHMS__c = system.now();

    update addendumTierFeature;

    addendumTierFeature.From_IHMS__c = system.now();


    update addendumTierFeature;

  }
}
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.  I believe the problem is in the way I am testing the approval process start.  Is there by chance a special testing function for this?

Comment: That error message looks like it might be truncated. Are you sure that is all of it?

Comment: Nope, that's the whole thing.  That is the error that shows up in the IDE.  In the log there is a little bit of text in front of it, like a time stamp.  I just ran the test class again and got the same phrasing.  Should there be more to it?

Comment: Yes, it would normally say "caused by" and then the exception, e.g. "caused by null pointer exception". Can you post the next 10 or so lines of log after the error please?

Comment: or just pastebin the lot

Comment: Alrighty, I've created a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/avEU2AwZ . You can see the error around line 1505. Now that I'm looking at it a little closer it looks like it may be caused by the failure to load another test class "AddOptionsTest".  But that test class is completely unrelated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling around for a little while I discovered that the error was actually tied into my approval process.  I kept digging into the error logs until I got to the error: `caused by: System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MANAGER_NOT_DEFINED, Manager undefined.: []`.  This phrase indicates that there is no one defined for the next step in my approval process.

When I created the opportunity, I did not set the owner and somehow this created an opportunity which had an owner without a manager.  The addendum was also created without an owner/manager.  So when I tried to launch the next approval process, there was no manager to send the approval to and an error was thrown.